# How to bind single functionality for multiple div id

Tags: jquery, css

I want to use tool tip for large number of lists

I wrote a jquery for every div, but i dont know to bind a functionality for multiple div items

Here is the link 
http://masterssoftware.in/tool_tip2.html
and below the mentioned code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a1_down").hover(function(){
        $("#tip1_down").toggle();
        });

    $("#a2_down").hover(function(){
        $("#tip2_down").toggle();
        }); 

        $("#a3_down").hover(function(){
        $("#tip3_down").toggle();
        }); 


    });

</script>
<style>
body{ background:#690;}
.tip{ width:500px; height:100px; padding:10px; background:#CFF; display:none; overflow:hidden; border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px; z-index:200; position:absolute;}
.tip h4{ display:block; font-size:18px; text-transform:uppercase;}
.tip p{ font-size:14px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
   <li><a id="a1_down" href="#">aaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
<div id="tip1_down" class="tip"> <h4>content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa </h4>
 <p>content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>

<li><a id="a2_down" href="#">aaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
<div id="tip2_down" class="tip"> <h4>content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa </h4>
 <p>content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
<li><a id="a3_down" href="#">aaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
<div id="tip3_down" class="tip"> <h4>content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa </h4>
 <p>content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa content of aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using IDs, you can use `parent` and `next` methods:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li a").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().toggle()
    });
});
```

Or using classes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul a.classname").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('.tip').toggle()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the anchors a class and use that in the selector or target all anchors within the selector like below:

```
 $("ul li a").hover(function(){

    $(this).parent().find('.tip').toggle();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all `a`  tags whose `id`  ends in `_down`.
2. Apply function to `tip` + index fetched from `a` 's id.

```js
$("a[id$='_down']").hover(function(){
    $("#tip" + $(this).prop('id')[1] + "_down").toggle(); // modify it if more than 10 indexes exist
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and put it on every div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toolTip").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for "use a class" since an ID should be unique. That's what an ID is for.